# Image hover does not display display div

Tags: html, css

I have to create an image in html and add css hover to display a div on top of the image whenever the user hovers over it.

I have tried adding `image:hover` to my css but it does not seem to work and I can't understand why.

Here is my html

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="image">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/example.png" alt="Website" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <a class="portfolio-box" href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
          <div class="project-name">Example</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image:hover .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f86d27;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: remove `opacity: 0;` form `.image:hover .overlay`

Comment: thank you, not even sure why I added that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the commentarys mentioned you have to remove `opacity:0;`. It will make your on hover placed styles be invisible.

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image:hover .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f86d27;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="image">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/example.png" alt="Website" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <a class="portfolio-box" href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
          <div class="project-name">Example</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```